# Background color not appearing in <div> content

Tags: html, css, image

> The background color is not appearing, I want to set the social media icons with some background color which covers the whole webpage width and a specific height.

```
    <div class = "social-media">
        <div class="middle">
            <a class="btn" href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn" href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn" href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn" href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
    </>
```

> CSS:

```
.social-media{
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
height: 10%;
}
```

Comment: add `width;` also, it will show the color. https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/x36pr1jL/7/

Answer (score 1):

Set width to CSS Class

```
.social-media{
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    width:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `left:0` and `right:0` position.

```
.social-media{
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
height: 10%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify width and height too.